# Sturm Liouville BVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am stuck with the following Sturm Liouville Boundary Value Problem:

$(1+x^2)y^" + 2xy^{\prime} + \lambda x^2 y = 0 \ $ with $ \ y^{\prime}(1)=0 , \  y^{\prime}(10)=0$

$\Rightarrow \frac d {dx} ((1+x^2)\frac {dy} {dx}) + \lambda x^2 y =0 \ $ with $ \ y^{\prime}(1)=0 , \  y^{\prime}(10)=0$

For the case $\lambda = 0$, the ode is pretty simple. But for nonzero values of $\lambda$ I'm not being able to solve it for nozero $\lambda$ cases (as I'm unable to come up with any suitable substitution which will transform the given ode with an ode with constant coefficient). Can anyone suggest how to proceed for nonzero lambda values. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what are the "substitution" you are looking for. You have first to set it under the form $\displaystyle {\frac {\mathrm {d} }{\mathrm {d} x}}\!\!\left[\,p(x){\frac {\mathrm {d} y}{\mathrm {d} x}}\right]+q(x)y=-\lambda \,w(x)y$...

Comment: You mentioned this is a BVP, but I don't see the boundary conditions. What are they? They're always extremely important.

Comment: @AdrianKeister I had forgotten to mention the boundary conditions. Thank you very much for pointing out. I have updated it.

Comment: @JeanMarie as the ode is with variable coefficients, I was trying to substitute x by some function of t in such a way that the ode gets converted into an ode with constant coefficients.

Comment: You'll have to work with the ODE as is.

Comment: $y(x)=0,$ the trivial solution, works here. You might not actually have other solutions. Have you worked out what the eigenfunctions of the operator are?

Comment: @AdrianKeister : This is certainly true for random values of $λ$. Those where non-trivial solutions exist are the eigenvalues.